# Codelite never made an .exe with my project

Tags: compiler-errors, exe, codelite

This may seem really simple if you already know the answer but I just downloaded v9 64bit of Codelite. Every project i create is not only missing an .exe file but the entire Debug folder. So every time i try to run the program it outputs a blank page because there is nothing to reference...exe. Am i missing something when making the project, is there a button to create the debug folder (i have already tried "rebuild workspace".

When i create a project I use Console>Simple executable (gcc).

Because the debug folder is missing with the exe file i cant debug or run any code I may type up. What am I missing here

Comment: Did any file been created?

Comment: The only thing created was the Workspace file. and the project file. the Source C file and the Mark File

Comment: what happened when you hit `F7` (Build) ? (the build output can be very handy here...)